# Question about the use of "both"

Tags: grammar, phrases, word-usage

Yesterday, I came across this sentence:

> *"I have attended different english language courses in the USA and Great Britain both."*

Is this a correct use of the word "both"? If not, how should the sentence be structured?

Comment: The sentence you're asking about uses *both* correctly, though in the US (where I'm from) it might seem a little unusual.  It strikes me as British.  (It should be ***the** USA,* though, and USA should be all caps.)

Comment: To my BrE ear it doesn't sound unnatural at all, if anything slightly formal. Other than that, using *both* at the end of a sentence like that is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Sorry, but I still say it's incorrect given the context. I'm not saying you can't use 'both' at the end of a sentence, I'm saying it sounds incorrect based on its context. 


'Movie A and movie B came out last night, we watched them both.' This is one such example. Of course, if the sentence presented by the OP was taken from a piece of seventy year old British literature, then perhaps it's just ignorance on my part. I'm not well versed in the classics.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey To my British ear it sounds grammatical but rather old fashioned, or possibly even pretentious. There also seems to be something awkward about the sentence as a whole, but I can't put my finger on what it is. I think it's related to the relative complexity of the first part of the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's fine.  "Both" in your example is a floated quantifier -- the quantifier of a noun phrase is converted to an adverb, which winds up somewhere after the noun phrase. Details differ, but "all" and "each" can sometimes float, also.

Answer (score -1):

I have attended different language courses in both the USA and Great Britain.

Comment: While this answer is correct, it fails to note that the sentence being asked about is also correct, at least as far as the use of *both.*